# JS Switch Case - Execute function for case block

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Is it possible to execute a case block based on a function call/expression evaluation?

```
function decideRandomName(name) {
let n
    switch (name) {
        case name.toString().toUpperCase().startsWith("A"): // Is this possible?
            console.log("here")
            n = "Andshand"
            break;
        case name.toString().toUpperCase().startsWith("B"):
            n = "Bandshand"
            break;
        default:
            n = "Pandu saala"
    }
    return n;
}
```

When i execute this, it always executes the default block. If this kind of syntax is not supported then i believe js to throw me an error? Can someone explain the concept here?

Answer (score 3):

Just switch for truthyness:

```
 switch (true) { }
```

However in your case you could do:

```
 return {
  "J": "Jonas",
  "A": "Albert"
 }[name[0].toUpperCase()] || "default";
```

Comment: Can you also explain the return object syntax you used? And if i am not wrong that return statement is a replacement for switch?

Comment: @eNthUsiAst yes it is.

Comment: Can you also please explain this syntax? or provide a link to documentation usage of this syntax?

Comment: Thats just an object and bracket access notation.

Comment: But how does that work as a switch? It should simply return the entire object?

Comment: No it will return the value that is related to the key `name[0].toUpperCase()`

Comment: Dunno. Maybe *immeadiately accessed object literal (iaol)* ? :)

Answer (score 1):

[Switch statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) are used to evaluate different possible values of an expression. They can be used where you might otherwise have a control flow structure like this:

```js
if(someLetter === "A") {
    // do whatever for "A"
} else if (someLetter === "B") {
    // do whatever for "B"
} else if (someLetter === "C") {
    // etc.,
    // etc., and like so for D through Z
    // etc., 
} else {
    // default action
}
```

In your code, `name` is (presumably) a string.  But, [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith), `.startsWith()` returns true or false. So your cases are basically equivalent to `case false:` and `case false:`. And, since the **value** of `name` is not false, you're not hitting those cases.

I updated your code to demonstrate the intended usage of `switch`.

```js
function decideRandomName(name) {
    let n;
    let firstLetter = name[0].toUpperCase();
    switch (firstLetter) {
        case "A": 
            console.log("here")
            n = "Andshand"
            break;
        case "B":
            n = "Bandshand"
            break;
        default:
            n = "Pandu saala"
            break;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The matching that occurs between the expression passed to switch, (`name` in this case) and each case expression is identical to the `===` algorithm.

Since `name` (a `string` presumably) and `name.toString().toUpperCase().startsWith("A")` (a `boolean` value) can never be identical, none of the cases match and the `default` block is executed.

As a work around you could do as @Jonas suggested and check for truthyness by:

```
 switch (true) { }
```

Comment: Thanks, understood it now :)

Comment: @eNthUsiAst glad to have helped!